# VBA script to FTP a file from local to Unix server

Tags: unix, vba, ftp

I have a file at local system & i want to transfer (FTP) to unix location. 
I have Unix IP , user id & password with me. How do FTP a file using excel VBA script ?
Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Read this thread:

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=178371